# Need improve performance in below code with rxjava and hystrix

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, rx-java, hystrix

I need a help in improving performance in below code with rxjava, hystrix and jdbctemplate. below code takes 20mins for 8000 records and has memory issue too.
i am trying to take 100k product ids from table and hit the rest api to get latest price info for the products and insert the records into a temp table in DB and call oracle procedure to perform some action on the latest price values.
Note: all the functions end with commands are hystrix and returns Observable object and this job is expected to run daily once.

```
List<Price> PriceList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> errorSkus = new HashMap<>();
return Observable.zip(getErrProductsCommands, // error products from previous run
                getEligibleProductsCommands,// expected to return 100k product ids and returns List<String>
                (errProduct, eligiableProduct) -> {
                    LOGGER.info("inside zip ");
                    eligiableProduct.addAll(errProduct);
                    updateErrProductCommand(errProduct);// jdbctemplate batchupdate update as processed in error table.
                    LOGGER.info("eligiableProduct-->{}", eligiableProduct.size());
eligiableProduct.parallelStream().distinct().forEach( // using parallenStream but no improvement
                Product -> {
                    LOGGER.info("Product->{}", Product);
                    
                    Price Price = priceExternalAPICommand(Product).queue().get();//each external API calls takes 2 secs
                    if (Price != null) {
                        PriceList.add(Price);
                    } else {
                        errorProduct.put(Product, "Not Found");
                    } 
                }
        )
                    return PriceList;
                })//zip ends
                .flatMap(i -> Observable.zip(insertErrTableCommand(errorSkus), // insert error product in error table of current run, jdbctemplate batchupdate
                            insertTmpTableCommand(PriceList), (err, stg) -> true))// insert in Temp table as jdbctemplate batchupdate expected products 1 lakh. returns true always
                    .flatMap(callProc -> callOracleProcCommand)
                    .doOnError(i -> {
                        LOGGER.info("doOnError -{0}", i.getCause());
                        (..send mail);
                    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe();
```

Comment: Querying 100k product prices individually is probably the main reason it goes that slow. You may need to ask for an external API that you can ask about 10-100 products at once.